# how can I read multiple inputs from stdin in c using fgets

Tags: c, stdin, fgets

I tried this code and the wrote another similar one to read another input but the program read in the second time both the first stdin and the second one (also I used fflush(stdin) instead of fseek() but that didn't work either)

```
     int BUFFERSIZE=100;
     char input[BUFFERSIZE];
     char *final=malloc(1);
     while(fgets(input,BUFFERSIZE-1,stdin))
     {
         final=realloc(final,strlen(final)+strlen(input)+1);
         strcat(final,input);
         if(input[strlen(input)-1]=='\n') break;

     }
     sscanf(final,"%d",&opt);
     free(final);
     fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
```

Comment: You can't seek in stdin unless it's redirected to a file.

Comment: Note: `-1` not needed in `fgets(input,BUFFERSIZE-1,stdin)`.  Suggest `fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't initialize the contents of the `final` buffer before the loop. So the first `strlen(final)` and `strcat(final, input)` are reading an uninitialized string, causing undefined behavior.

```
     int BUFFERSIZE=100;
     char input[BUFFERSIZE];
     char *final=malloc(1);
     *final = 0; // initialize to empty string
     while(fgets(input,BUFFERSIZE-1,stdin))
     {
         final=realloc(final,strlen(final)+strlen(input)+1);
         strcat(final,input);
         if(input[strlen(input)-1]=='\n') break;

     }
     sscanf(final,"%d",&opt);
     free(final);
```

Comment: you really saved me